# How to grab data from one response from two possible API text responses in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-split

There's two possible responses of my API. I need to grab data from the received text response and need to store them as variables.

API Calling:

```
  $url="http://91.101.61.111:99/SendRequest/?mobile=9999999999&id=11011&reqref=501";
  $request_timeout = 60;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $request_timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $request_timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_error = curl_errno($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

Possible API responses in plain text:

```
REQUEST ACCEPTED your ref=<myref> system_reference=<sysref>
Or,
REQUEST ERROR errorno=<error>;your ref=<myref>;system_reason=<sysreason>
```

In case of 1st possible response, I need to grab data like below:

```
$status = "REQUEST ACCEPTED";  
$myref = "501";  
$sysref = "BA01562";
```

And in case of 2nd possible response, I need to grab data like below:

```
$status = "REQUEST ERROR";
$error = "25";
$myref = "501";
$sysreason = "Duplicate request";
```

I have tried:

```
$response = preg_match('/([\w\s]+) ([\w]+)/', $output, $res);
$rstatus = $res[1];

if ($rstatus == "REQUEST ACCEPTED")
{
    $raccepted = preg_match('/([\w\s]+) your ref=([\d]+) system_reference=([\w]+)/', $output, $matches);
    $status = $matches[1];  
    $myref = $matches[2];  
    $sysref = $matches[3];  
}
elseif ($rstatus == "REQUEST ERROR")
{
    $rerror = preg_match('/([\w\s]+) errorno=([\d]+);your ref=([\d]+);system_reason=([\w\s]+)/', $output, $matches);
    $status = $matches[1];
    $error = $matches[2]; 
    $myref = $matches[3];  
    $sysreason = $matches[4];  
}

echo "Status is $status, My Ref ID is $myref";
```

Now, when I get the 1st possible response from API call, I always get the errors on the last line (echo ....), like below:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: status
>   ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: myref
>   Status is , My Ref ID is

But no issues when I receive the 2nd response. It shows as I want:

> Status is REQUEST ERROR, My Ref ID is 501

Please help!

Comment: Why don't you make the API responses into some better format, like json? Even XML would be better. Seems strange to have a custom response that requires manual parsing like that.

Comment: `$rStatus` = `REQUEST ACCEPTED your`, so it won't match. I agree with Magnus Eriksson, create a more sane response from your API.

Comment: ...even worse... you actually have _two different_, and custom, formats depending on if the request was accepted or not.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the most efficient method, try using some proper format like `JSON` or something. Anyway, here is a solution:

```
$success = stristr($output, "REQUEST ACCEPTED");

if($success)
{
    $data = stristr($output, "ref");
    $raccepted = preg_match('/ref=([\d]+) system_reference=([\w]+)/', $data, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
else
{
    $data = stristr($output, "errorno");
    $rerror = preg_match('/errorno=([\d]+);your ref=([\d]+);system_reason=([\w\s]+)/', $data, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but preg_match is faster then strstr

Comment: @tsv Not saying it isn't true, but do you have any reference for that statement that fits this situation?

Comment: This answer is also more readable and will give the OP all the different values from the response.

Comment: preg_match vs strstr
execution time preg match: 0.0034110546112061
Total execution time strstr: 0.00382399559021. I try many times and have same results

Comment: @tsv Those times are too close to call. You need to do it around 1000 times and count the averages. You should also use the actual code from this answer, if you want to do a real comparison. You're doing `strstr("REQUEST ACCEPTED", '/\w+ \w+/is', "REQUEST ACCEPTED your ref=some system_reference=some123");` which isn't the correct way of using that function. [Check the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: @tsv: *"preg_match is faster th[a]n strstr"*: no it's wrong.

Comment: @tsv Here's a test, doing both 1000 times and showing the average: https://3v4l.org/YTRiM

Comment: I recheck. Yes, i was wrong everage test shows that strstr is faster in this case. Sorry for this and thanks for true direction.
I have Total execution time preg match: 3.3812522888184E-6 and Total execution time strstr: 1.7762184143066E-6

Answer (score 0):

You should change your regular expression

```
$response = preg_match('/([\w\s]+) ([\w]+)/', $output, $res);
```

to

```
$response = preg_match('/\w+ \w+/is', $output, $res);
```

Test:

```
php > preg_match('/\w+ \w+/is', "REQUEST ACCEPTED your ref=some system_reference=some123", $res);
php > var_dump($res);
php shell code:1:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(16) "REQUEST ACCEPTED"
}
php > preg_match('/\w+ \w+/is', "REQUEST ERROR errorno=123;your ref=SOMEref;system_reason=reason", $res);
php > var_dump($res);
php shell code:1:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(13) "REQUEST ERROR"
}
```

Other recommendations:

1. Trim you response before test regular for using ^ and $ (begin and end of your regular part).
2. Use === instead == in this case
3. check exists $res[1]; before $rstatus = $res[1];